# How to remove blue border around NG-ZORRO (antd for Angular) buttons when hovering over them?

Tags: antd, ng-zorro-antd

If you click this link it takes you to a few examples on their page.

https://ng.ant.design/components/button/en

I am able to access the buttons and change the color but not the actual blue border.  I have tried :active, :hover, :focus, etc..

This is how I access the button for some custom css

```
.ant-btn-circle {
  background-color: $theme-foreground !important;
  color: rgb(var(--MainColor)) !important;
}

.ant-btn-circle:focus {
  background-color: rgb(var(--MainColor)) !important;
  color: $theme-foreground !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
}
```

The outline portion doesn't seem to work... Any tips?

I see something like this that has the blue color but I dont know what it is.  --antd-wave-shadow-color

```
html {
font-family: sans-serif;
line-height: 1.15;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;



--antd-wave-shadow-color: #1890ff;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I found so far is creating a theme.less file in your src and adding this:

```
@import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less";

@primary-color: #6D6E70;
```

So I guess it is the primary color.  Would be nice to set it custom. In the css.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by setting the transition period for the button's border-color property to 0ms.

So using your example:

```
.ant-btn-circle {
  transition: border-color 0ms;
}
```